# Flutter reopen app via email authentication

Tags: flutter, mobile-development, nhost

I'm trying to add passwordless auth to my Flutter iOS/Android app.

I'm currently using NHost as a back-end and receiving the correct link after the user enters their email.

The issue is that I couldn't figure out how to re-open the app after the user taps on the unique link and extracts the token from the URL.

Could anyone please give me some ideas on what would be the best way to launch the app again from the email page? Thank you